# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, nginx version

Tags: nginx, versions

I am a bit surprised by the version of nginx which comes with the new LTS version of Ubuntu.

Why is it only the 1.18 version for Ubuntu 22.04, it's the same version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Is there any official more recent release, like 1.20.2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: The math is pretty simple: More volunteer Debian packagers = More and newer software in both Debian and Ubuntu. Fewer volunteers = Less and older software. Folks who want to help can start their journey at http://mentors.debian.net. FYI: nginx 1.22 will be in Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: also keep in mind that Ubuntu gets its NGINX from Debian, and until this year (*after 22.04* came out) it was relatively unmaintained in Debian.  Both myself and another maintainer have stepped up in Debian and now track Stable releases which come out every year, though they aren't precisely released before Ubuntu LTS comes out.  Which is why you get the 'older' releases seemingly.  This is caused by NGINX upstream's release schedules.

Answer (score 0):

Use the nginx official repository as the latest nginx version is not yet added in Ubuntu Jammy (Ubuntu 22.04) repositories.

Run the following command to add the nginx repository according to Ubuntu codename.

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

Additional information in this blog:
https://medium.com/@bhojport/installing-a-specific-version-of-nginx-on-ubuntu-or-any-other-platform-4fed8e859534

Comment: You forgot how to import the gpg key so this would actually work and not error out on `apt update` which makes this answer incomplete.